# Magento site down 403 forbidden/ hacked

Tags: magento, http-status-code-403

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The file permissions for index.php has been changed to 0000 and if I change it to 0755 or even delete the file, index.php gets recreated by itself.

Error log does not show anything.

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/ is unable to run malware scans on the website as the website returns 403 Forbidden.

Please guide

Comment: cpanel works fine and i have already changed the password

Comment: the contents of index.php is generic? if you delete it how soon is it recreated? are there any cronjobs running?

Comment: Found the cause it is shared hosting and the service provider has disabled index.php because it is causing too much load on the server. Maybe I'll have to enable cache and disable logging to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the cause it is shared hosting and the service provider has disabled index.php because it is causing too much load on the server. Maybe I'll have to enable cache and disable logging to improve performance.

Your hosting provider has found Magento to be too intense a load on their server and has removed the ability to run it. Magento does not play well with others and hates sharing resources with others. Small sites can only be run on shared hosting if you have a hosting service provider that optimizes their servers for use with Magento and vastly limits the number of sites per server.

It's time for you to find a hosting provider that understands hosting Magento.